# sql server 2000 convert datetime to get hhmm

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using

```
convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 112)
```

to convert getdate() to yyyymmdd format (ISO format), which works great.  Now I need to do something similiar to get the time in hhmm format.  How can I achieve this?

Example: 12:10 pm should look like 1210, 3:43 pm should look like 1543.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: @MarcB -Your suggesting I get the datepart for the hours, get the datepart for the minutes, and concantenate?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
```

Comment: that is military time.  It actually take more work to get a 12 hour clock out of it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx Instead of 108, you can also use 8, 14 or 114 to get the same results.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(5),GETDATE(),108), ':', '')
```

If you don't need colon, just remove it...

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT do just the datepart for the hours, get the datepart for the minutes, and concatenate as 19:05 will end up 195.  If you go this route, you'll need to do something like this to deal with minutes:

right('0' + varchar(datepart(mi,getdate())),2)

at this point it's getting pretty inefficient.